# Dark mode not appearing as an option on ipad, how to make it appear?

Tags: ipad

I wanted to use dark mode on my ipad.

I tried the standard suggestion (based of [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210332)):

- `Setting | Display & Control`

then there should be a nice picture to toggle dark mode. The option is not there.

I found a different option from [this webpage](https://www.support.com/how-to/how-to-turn-on-dark-mode-iphone-ipad-or-ipod-touch-12741) to go to:

- `Setting | Control Center | Customize Controls`

then they claim there should be an option for dark mode, but it's not there.

Thus, I am unsure what to do. I've restarted the ipad and tried updating but the update option is not there.

Why is it not working?

---

Perhaps some info of my ipad specs might help?

```
Software Version: 12.4.6
Model Name: iPad air
Model Number: ME898LL/A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 12 doesn't have Dark Mode. It was new to iOS 13.

You can achieve something similar by going to

> Settings > General > Accessibility and choose Display Accommodations. Then click Invert Colours.

> If you want to go all funhouse crazy, toggle the Classic Invert mode. But to get an inverted iOS that's closer to a true dark mode, you'll want to select Smart Invert. That way iOS 12 actually tries to keep things from going too crazy.

Courtesy of [Forbes - iOS 12.4 Public Beta 4 Released, Is Boring, Here's How To Get Dark Mode Now](https://www.forbes.com/sites/anthonykarcz/2019/06/12/ios-12-4-public-beta-4-released-is-boring-heres-how-to-get-dark-mode-now/)

Your iPad Air ME898LL/A 4,1 unfortunately cannot use iOS 13, it is stuck at 12. Info: [Everymac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/specs/apple-ipad-air-1st-gen-a1474-wi-fi-only-specs.html)

Comment: ok thanks good to know my iPad cannot be upgraded (sad :( )